# List BigQuery tables which don't have primary keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

BigQuery now supports primary keys as a table constraints [LINK](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-constraints)!

However, how do I list the tables within a BigQuery dataset which explicitly don't have primary keys enabled?

Answer (score 1):

The BigQuery [Information_Schema TABLE_CONSTRAINTS view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-constraints#examples) does include examples of how to explicitly list the tables which are configured with primary keys. However, to pull a list of tables which explicitly do not have primary keys, the TABLE_CONSTRAINTS and TABLES Information_Schemas can be combined to pull this data.

A query like the below should work:

```
SELECT
    table_catalog as project_id,
    table_schema as dataset_id,
    table_name as table_id
FROM <your_dataset>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES as all_tbls
EXCEPT DISTINCT
SELECT 
  table_catalog as project_id,
  table_schema as dataset_id,
  table_name as table_id
FROM <your_dataset>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS as cdc_tbls
WHERE constraint_type = "PRIMARY KEY"
```